# As per my pattern, the output is not a meaningful word. Can anyone identify a different pattern to output a meaningful word

Tags: javascript, java, html

As per my pattern, the output is not a meaningful word. Can anyone identify a different pattern to output a meaningful word.

Consider the following pattern:
A → D;         M → P;       X → A;
a → d;         m → p;       x → a;

Solve the following message

Vrphwklqj phdqlqjixo

Hint: The answer is something meaningful.

I am considering that there should be a difference of two alphabets; which outputs: Yuskznotm.....(not meaningful at all).

Can anyone see a different pattern and help me out.

Comment: This is a homework question if I've ever seen one.  What's your attempt?

Comment: This seems like a caesar cipher using + 3. Have you tried different numbers?

Comment: Step 1: Try to work it out yourself. Step 2: If you run into trouble, post the code you're having trouble with. You've skipped step 1. Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The question is wrong
The pattern should be D->A,P->M,X->U
That is Caesar cipher using -3 or +23 (NOT +3)
READ THE QUESTION PROPERLY
USE THIS TO CHECK
    `import java.io.*;
    class CaesarCipher 
    {
     public static void main(String s)throws IOException
      {
        for(int i=1;i<27;i++)
        {
          int l=s.length();
          for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
           if(Character.isLetter(s.charAt(j)))
           {
            if(((s.charAt(j))+i)>122)
             System.out.print((char)((s.charAt(j))+i-26));
            else
             System.out.print((char)((s.charAt(j))+i));
            }
           else
            System.out.print((char)s.charAt(j));
          System.out.println();
        }
    }
    }`
ONLY LOWERCASE LETTERS
It adds a new shift every time to create a new string
1,2,3,......,26
You can see the answer for your question when adding 23 or by also subtracting 3 which should be the real question which you mistook
IT WILL DISPLAY ALL POSSIBLE CAESAR DECRYPTIONS LOOK WHAT'S MEANINGFUL

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paulsam. You got it right. There was a discrepancy in the assignment question. I figured it and wrote a javascript for it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ceaser-Cipher-Convertion</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
```

//This function takes the input and defines the logic for conversion

```
 function convert() 
        {
```

//The input to be converted to the message is provided here

```
  var input = "Vrphwklqj phdqlqjixo";
```

/* The convertion logic is based on Ceaser-Cipher method. We retrieve the ASCII values of the characters one be one from the string.
    As per formulae; m = c + d mod 26. However we are using ASCII values, we have to replace mod 26 by - 26.
    The decryption key from the pattern is 23. Hence m = c + 23-26 => m = c - 23. However for the ASCII values; a-c; the formulae returns 
    non-alphabetic ASCII values. As an exception to these three alphabets; m = c + 23;
    The ASCII value thus attained are to be converted back to characters */

```
 for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++)
            {
                var asc_code = input.charCodeAt(i);
                var conv_code;

                //Conversion of alphabets (a-c)
                if((asc_code >= 65 && asc_code <= 67) || (asc_code >= 97 && asc_code <= 99))
                {
                     conv_code = asc_code+23;
                }
```

//Conversion of rest of the alphabets

```
else if((asc_code >= 68 && asc_code <= 90) || (asc_code >= 100 && asc_code <= 122))
                {
                    conv_code = asc_code-3;
                }
```

//Conversion of non alphabetic characters

```
     else conv_code = asc_code;
```

//Output the message

```
                        var message = String.fromCharCode(conv_code);
                        document.write(message);
                }
            }

            convert();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```